# Does R's Time-Series automatically generate missing data?

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, imputation

I was wondering if anyone with knowledge on R's time-series from the stats package could help me out.

I'm currently generating a Time-Series using stat's ts function.

I'm passing the ts function a data set (with 3 years worth of dates and numeric values for each day), the start and end date that have been parsed as a decimal date, and the frequency of 365. 
However, there are certain ranges of dates missing (for example, dates and values from April 30th, 2016 to January 2nd, 2017 are missing).

However, when I view or plot the time series, I noticed that the missing data is automatically filled with values.

I'm not sure how these values have been generated.

Does the time series function automatically fill in missing dates with their data?

Thanks for any help,
Jay

Edit:
Example of part of my original data frame:
(you can see that there are missing data from 2016-04-30 to 2017-01-02)

```
 Dataframe:
             date          pieceVolume
 ...   |      ...       |     ...  
 615   |   2016-04-29   |    250.5  
 616   |   2016-04-30   |    1230.4  
 617   |   2017-01-02   |    273.2  
 618   |   2017-01-01   |    26150.5  
 619   |   2017-01-02   |    232550.7
```

My original data frame has 655 rows, but my time series has a length of 1079.
This is how I'm generating my timeseries from the data frame:

```
sts <- ts(test_data$pieceVolume, start=decimal_date(min(as.Date(test_data$date))), end=decimal_date(max(as.Date(test_data$date))), frequency=365)
```

My Original Code:

```
original_data <- readRDS("original_data.rds")
library(plyr)
## Using ddply to average all the pieceVolumes that have the same dates.
test_data <- plyr::ddply(original_data, .(date), function(x) c(pieceVolume=mean(x$pieceVolume)))
library("forecast")
## Generate time-series using test_data
sts <- ts(test_data$pieceVolume, start=decimal_date(min(as.Date(test_data$date))), end=decimal_date(max(as.Date(test_data$date))), frequency=365)
```

Comment: Hmm, are you removing NA's when you load the data? Can add some data to your problem? Are you sure those dates are not completely removed? Did you check the length of the original set vs the converted time series set?

Comment: @DataTx there are no NAs. The missing data are completely missing (There are no rows at all for the missing dates)

Comment: it may not be plotting missing dates at all. Check the length of the times series with `length(df$timeseries)` or with `dim`. If it's less than 365 then nothing is plotted for missing dates

Comment: I'm getting a length of 1079, which I believe is valid since I'm passing in 3 years of data.

Comment: The thing is, my original data set only has 655 row.

Comment: post your original code

Comment: Okay I have posted my original code

Comment: have you tried the results if you just did `sts<- ts(test_data$pieceVolume)`

Comment: Okay, it seems like (`sts<- ts(test_data$pieceVolume)`) is giving a valid result. So passing in the start and end date and frequency is resulting in 'interpolation'/random generation of data?

Comment: Do you happen to know how this data is being generated? If it is actual interpolation or just repeating random data points

Comment: Okay. Found the answer to the last question. It's just going through the original data set, and then going back to the start and repeating from the first entry again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sts<- ts(test_data$pieceVolume)
```

Comment: It seems that when I generate the time-series, something is automatically interpolating the data for me. It's generating the missing dates automatically, although I have not done anything to interpolate it. I'm wondering if the ts function automatically interpolating it for me.

Comment: Please explain what your code does differently from OP's and how that solves the problem or answers the question. I recommend this guide on creating a useful answer stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer